# Can't save a frozen Map to IndexedDB in Safari on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, mobile-safari, indexeddb

On iOS 14 and up (I haven't verified with lower versions), I'm unable to save any frozen `Map` into IndexedDB. I'm not aware if it happens for things other than `Map`. Here's a piece of code that I tested this through:

```
let testMap = new Map();
testMap.set("person1", {
    name: "John Doe",
    id: 1
});

Object.freeze(testMap);

// Skipping over code to create the store for accessing IndexedDB
store.add(testMap);
```

The `store.add(testMap)` fails with: `DataCloneError: The object can not be cloned.` If I don't `Object.freeze`, it succeeds. I don't encounter this issue with other devices.